# How to display certain data using block helper meteor js

Tags: meteor

I have two categories which is ICT and non-ICT. I just want display data that belongs to ICT. Can someone show me the solution?

**List.html**

```
  <template name="showList">

        {{#each List}}
            {{#if category_name="ICT"}}
                {{> ItemList}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </template>

 <template name="ItemList">  

    <td>{{category_name}} </td> 
    <td>{{subcategory_name}} </td> 
    <td>{{item_name}} </td>
    <td>{{date1}} </td>
    <td>{{date2}} </td>
    <td>{{status}} </td>

 </tr>

</template>
```

**List.js**

```
Template.showList.helpers({
    list: function(){
        return List.find();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper should be changed into

```
Template.showList.helpers({
    list: function(){
        return List.find({category_name: "ICT"});
    }
});
```

By the way, you have a typo in your code. It is `{{#each list}}`, not `{{#each List}}`

Comment: please set this as the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should define the category name in your helper.

HTML:

```
<template name="showList">
    {{#each List}}
        {{> ItemList}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.showList.helpers({
    list: function(){
        return List.find({category_name: "ICT"});
    }
});
```